# MarkLogic String Query NOT NOT_IN logic

Tags: string, parsing, marklogic

Is there String query search grammar as matching occurrences of 'private' and 'doe' and excluding the phrase 'Jane Doe' ?

```
const searchString = 'private AND doe NOT_IN "Jane Doe" ';
```

Comment: please explain the version you are using as well as API you are using for searching

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems below works!

```
const searchQuery = 'private AND doe - "Jane Doe"';
```

Comment: Yes, minus sign seems the way:  https://docs.marklogic.com/10.0/guide/search-dev/search-api#id_44520